# Extract <im:rating> from apple feeds with simplepie

Tags: php, xml, simplepie

I use simplepie only for parse itunes feeds and i want to extract im:rating :

```
<entry>
<updated>2014-04-18T04:44:00-07:00</updated>
<id>978910847</id>
<title>anything</title>
<content type="text">
any description here
</content>
<im:contentType term="Application" label="Application"/>
<im:voteSum>0</im:voteSum>
<im:voteCount>0</im:voteCount>
<im:rating>5</im:rating>
<im:version>1.5</im:version>
<author>
<name>any name</name>
<uri>https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id</uri>
</author>
<link rel="related" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/review?id=&type=Purple%20Software"/>
<content type="html"></content>
</entry>
```

Any idea plz ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that SimplePie supports this format with its rating class?

Comment: i found the solution : 
define("SIMPLE_NAMESPACE_IM", "http://itunes.apple.com/rss");
$data = $item->get_item_tags(SIMPLE_NAMESPACE_IM, 'rating');
$stars = $data[0]['data'];

Comment: You should place that as an answer below (that's perfectly fine here on stackoverflow to answer your own question, it's even what we want :)). additionally use a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: @user3564413: You should really create an answer out of the solution you've left in the comment. Then select your own answer as "the answer" (see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This will then mark this question as answered *and* solved. Which would be great.